# Manually joining entity specified in contain

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-4.x

This is the SQL query that I'm trying to replicate in CakePHP.

```
$sql = "select sl.name_en, l.*
        from service_line_entries sle 
            inner join escalation_entries ee on ee.service_line_entry_id=sle.id
            inner join service_lines sl on sle.service_line_id=sl.id
            inner join audit_logs l on l.primary_key = ee.id and l.source='escalation_entries'
        where sle.request_id=69060
order by sl.name_en asc, created asc";
```

Essentially, `ServiceLineEntries` hasOne `EscalationEntries` and `ServiceLines` belongsTo `ServiceLinentries`.

The `AuditLogs` table is populated by the `AuditStash` behavior, thus contains audit data from many different tables in my app identified in the column `source`.

Here is my CakePHP code:

```
$this->ServiceLineEntries = TableRegistry::getTableLocator()->get('ServiceLineEntries');

$sle = $this->ServiceLineEntries->find()
->contain(['EscalationEntries'])
->join([
    'table' => 'audit_logs',
    'alias' => 'AuditLogs',
    'type' => 'INNER',
    'conditions' => [
        "AuditLogs.primary_key = EscalationEntries.id", 
        "AuditLogs.source = 'escalation_entries'"
    ],
])
->where(['ServiceLineEntries.request_id'=>69060]);
```

Errors:

`Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'EscalationEntries.id' in 'on clause'`

It doesn't work even if I specify the physical table name

```
'conditions' => [
    "AuditLogs.primary_key = escalation_entries.id", 
    "AuditLogs.source = 'escalation_entries'"
],
```

`Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'escalation_entries.id' in 'on clause'`

Edit #1: need to see columns from AuditLogs.

Edit #2: using the raw SQL, I can in theory massage the variable to make it easier to loop in the template:

```
$sql = "select sl.name_en, l.*
        from service_line_entries sle 
            inner join escalation_entries ee on ee.service_line_entry_id=sle.id
            inner join service_lines sl on sle.service_line_id=sl.id
            inner join audit_logs l on l.primary_key = ee.id and l.source='escalation_entries'
        where sle.request_id=69060
        order by sl.name_en asc, created asc";

$connection = ConnectionManager::get('default');
$results = $connection->execute($sql)->fetchAll('assoc');

$out = [];
foreach($results as $r)
{
    $out[$r['name_en']][] = $r;
}
```

Comment: Try explicitly joining on `EscalationEntries`? The query should do that already if it's a `hasOne` association as you've said, but maybe it happens in the wrong order or something. Also, try turning on SQL logging and look at the exact query/queries being generated for this call to get some insight into what's going wrong.

Comment: @GregSchmidt `EscaltionEntries` isn't the problem, it's `AuditLogs`. It can't really have any built in relationships as it's generic to all other tables reporting audit data into it. Thus, I have to join to it manually using the two columns.

Comment: But your error message says `Unknown column 'EscalationEntries.id' in 'on clause'`. I'm not suggesting that you don't manually join with `AuditLogs`, I'm suggesting that you try *also* manually joining on `EscalationEntries`, before `AuditLogs`.

Comment: @gregschmidt I belive the error on `EscalationEntries` is from the conditions specified in the manual join to `AuditLogs`? If I omit the manual join, my query is fine, the built in associations work as intended.

The `AuditLogs` should only join `EscalationEntries` on the two columns: primary_key=id and source='escalation_entries'. This mirrors the raw SQL I prototyped with.